# python error while installing pptx

Tags: python, installation, python-pptx

I would like to install the pptx package and i tried below. My main goal is to run the code which is provided at the bottom of [this page](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#extract-all-text-from-slides-in-presentation).

I have the latest version of PIP and I get the message

```
Collecting pptx
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pptx (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pptx


(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3) C:\WINDOWS\system32>easy_install -U pip
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Best match: pip 18.0
Processing pip-18.0-py3.6.egg
pip 18.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip-script.py script to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
Installing pip.exe script to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
Installing pip3-script.py script to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
Installing pip3.exe script to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
Installing pip3.6-script.py script to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
Installing pip3.6.exe script to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts

Using c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip-18.0-py3.6.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip

(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pptx
Collecting pptx
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pptx (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pptx

(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip -V
pip 18.0 from c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip-18.0-py3.6.egg\pip (python 3.6)

(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3) C:\WINDOWS\system32>

(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3) C:\Users\nnnn>
```

Answer (score 10):

Try running `pip install python-pptx` instead. It seems you are trying to find a package called `pptx` but that package does not exist on any of your registered channels.

Comment: that was quick and super helpful